# How to monitor Meteor.com server-side logs

Tags: logging, meteor

I'm looking for a way to get the server logs from a Meteor app deployed as myapp.meteor.com.
Ideally, a configuration or package I can use which will send in real-time the logs of the remote server to a local terminal (Linux/OSX). 
Is there a straight forward way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the built in meteor command to load the most recent logs:

```
meteor logs myapp.meteor.com
```

Works with `meteor mongo` too!

Comment: Thanks, that should work for me. Curious if there's a way to achieve the equivalent of 'tail -f' with this feature. Couldn't see anything in the command line help

Comment: Thank you for this one !