# Why Meteor.startup or $(window).load works only on localhost and not deployed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

In my Meteor.js project Meteor.startup runs only on localhost and not deployed. What causes this strange behavior? None of these runs on deployed version.

```js
Meteor.startup(function() {
  $('.carousel.slide').carousel();

  $("#inputdl").typed({
    strings: ["e.g. youtube.com/watch?v=WLGdXtZMmiI", "e.g. mixcloud.com/nicky-romero-protocol", "e.g. metacafe.com/ownage_pranks_hilarious", "e.g. twitch.tv/pokernighttv", "e.g. soundcloud.com/hucci/montana", "e.g. vine.co/playlists/mlb-2015", "e.g. vimeo.com/71278954"],
    attr: "placeholder", //attribute
    typeSpeed: 30, // typing speed
    startDelay: 500, // time before typing starts
    backSpeed: 3, // backspacing speed
    backDelay: 400, // pause before backspacing
    loop: true, // loop on or off (true or false)
    loopCount: false, // number of loops, false = infinite
    showCursor: true, // show cursor
    callback: function(){ } // call function after typing is done
  });

  Session.setDefault('button_value', 'Download');
  Session.setDefault('title', 'Paste URL and click Download');
});
```

Comment: All of that code looks like it should be in a template not on startup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Meteor.startup` fires on the client fires when the DOM has loaded. At this time, `.carousel.slide` and `#inputdl` may not be rendered yet, throwing an error. You should probably put that code in `Template.templatename.onRendered(func(...))` instead of in `Meteor.startup(...)`.

Have you checked the browser console? Do you see errors? If not, what happens if you get the jQuery code out and type in `Session.get('button_value')` in the browser console? Also check out the [server logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028282/how-to-monitor-meteor-com-server-side-logs) to see if something on the server goes arwy.

Do you have the most recent version of Meteor on your machine? Perhaps you have some deprecated functionality somewhere in your project. If everything fails (removing the jQuery code included), try creating a blank meteor project with `Meteor.startup(...)` in it. If it works then copy all your files over to that project and deploy, until you find that the deployed version is broken. (Quite cumberstone, but we can't check your whole project for errors.) If it doesn't work, then try it on a different machine. If that doesn't work, Meteor's deploy code or its server must be broken, but I find that unlikely.

Good luck!