# Method runs fine on local, will not run when deployed (on meteor.com)

Tags: javascript, meteor, web-deployment

I have a Meteor app that is running perfectly on local, but when I deploy to meteor.com, one method will not run.  All other methods run fine.

This is the relevant code:

**Client: Button click to add company to array**

```
Template.ValuationTableComps.events ({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var valuationId = this._id;
        var selection = {
        valuationSelections: $(e.target).find('[name=selectionComp]').val()};
        Valuations.update(valuationId, {$addToSet: selection}, function () {});
    }
});
```

**Client: Button click to re-run array based on selections above**

```
Template.ValuationCalc.events({
    'click #agg': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var valuationId = this._id;
        var valuationSelections = this.valuationSelections;
        Meteor.call('valuationAggregate', valuationId, valuationSelections, function (error, result) {});
    }
});
```

**Lib: method to run aggregation and upsert results into new collection**

```
Meteor.methods({
    valuationAggregate: function(valuationId, valuationSelections) {
        if (Meteor.isServer) {
            check(valuationId, String);
            check(valuationSelections, Array);
            var pipelineSelections = [
            //build pipeline//
            ];
            var results = Companies.aggregate(pipelineSelections);
            results.forEach(function(valuationResults) {
                ValuationResults.update({valuationId: valuationId}, valuationResults, {upsert: true});
            });
        }
    }});
```

This all works fine when running on local.  I can console.log `valuationId`, `valuationSelections` and `ValuationResults.find({valuationId:valuationId}).fetch()` on both the client and the server and all return the correct results.

When I deploy to meteor.com however, the method won’t run.  In my browser console, I see the `valuationId` and `valuationSelections`.  However, the ValuationResults query returns `[ ]`.

I have dummy data in ValuationResults that I can see in the browser console so the collection is fine.  But I don’t understand why the method would work on local but not on deployed.  This is the only thing that doesn't work, all others are fine.  Thank you.

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028282/how-to-monitor-meteor-com-server-side-logs

Comment: @JeremyK, thanks very much, I was able to see the error using your  suggestion, added resolution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:

I was able to run `meteor logs myApp` and saw there was an error `MongoError: exception: invalid operator '$literal'`.  My `$project` stage included  `valuationId: {$literal: valuationId}` to add a new field to the new document.  I don't know exactly why this is throwing an error, but there seems to be a known mongodb issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-668.

I took the `$literal` out of my pipeline and just updated the existing valuation document instead.  Works fine now on local and when deployed.